# Price return after announcement

Tags: price

Is it GUARANTEED that prices will return to their original price after a spike, such as after an NFP announcement?

Comment: Why do you think that they would? The world has changed and moved on and things will never be the same again! More seriously these announcements change the underlying economics AND the perception of the underlying economics. Prices may return to previous levels but there is no guarantee that they will even be within 10% of previous levels. It all depends on the size of the surprise and the exact meaning of the declared measure.

Comment: note: I'm not answering in a comment; I've marked it as too broad and explained why.

Comment: The only investment that is guaranteed not to lose  real money is on a virtual trader.

Comment: This question is on-topic, not too broad (meaning that a complete answer is not too long for our site), and it is not primarily opinion-based. It’s not the best question we’ve ever seen, but it should remain open.

Comment: @BenMiller I misread "prices" as "price levels" the answer with the former wording is a clear hollow laugh of no, the second is too broad. I'm rescinding my close vote

Answer (score 5):

> Is it guaranteed that prices will...

You can stop right there. The answer is no, prices in the future are not guaranteed. Ever.

Comment: +1 good point; I hadn't noticed that the question said "prices" rather than "price levels"